# Could anyone possible solve the polynomial eq!

Tags: polynomials

Find the roots for the following?
$x^4-x^3+2x^2-5x+3=0$

Comment: Try some rational root candidates, maybe?

Comment: What have you tried?  How do you usualy solve these equations? I'll help us give you a suitable answer.

Comment: Note $p(1)=0$, so $(x-1)$ is a factor of $p(x)$ (the function on the left side). So you can reduce this to at least a cubic and continue.

Comment: Yes we can, but need answer is wrong!

Comment: Answers are 1,1,(1+✓i)/2

Comment: @kashish There should be 4 roots for this equation.

Comment: Yes there are 4 roots!

Comment: @demonix_Hermit can you help me to obtain the roots properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**$$x^4 - x^3 + 2x^2 -5x+3 = (x-1)(x^3 +2x-3)$$
$$ = (x-1)^2(x^2+x+3)$$

Can you complete it from here ?